# Plotting with matplotlib in a for loop and storing mouse click locations for each plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a code to store mouse click locations on plots that are displayed in a for loop. Once a plot is displayed, the matplotlib notebook in jupyter displays the x and y locations by hovering the cursor on the plot. The user then clicks on the plot to choose x and y of interest which are to be stored.

I have written the following code to achieve the above description.

```
import numpy as np
from IPython import display
from IPython.display import clear_output
plt.close("all")
colour=['blue','red','green','black','magenta']
for num in range(len(df_save)):
    listed=[]
    for car,models in cars.items():
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        %matplotlib notebook
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        i=0
        for model in models.items():
            ax.plot(df_car[car+model][(df_car[car+model+'_Vel']<=df_save['VEL_MAX'][num]) & (df_car[car+model+'_Vel']>=df_save['VEL_MIN'][num])],
                df_car['emission'][(df_car[car+model+'_Vel']<=df_save['VEL_MAX'][num]) & (df_car[car+model+'_Vel']>=df_save['VEL_MIN'][num])],color=colour[i])
            ax.set_ylim(-0.15,1.25)
            ax.set_title(car,fontsize=20,family='serif', color='black')
            i=i+1
        plt.show()
        ques=input('Do you want to store components for this? ')
        if ques=='Y':
            ques1=input('Enter the number of components: ')
            coords = []
            def onclick(event):
                global ix, iy
                ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
                print ('x = %f, y = %f'%(ix, iy))
                global coords
                coords.append(ix, iy)
                if len(coords) == ques1:
                    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
                return coords
            cid=fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

            df_save['COMPONENTS'][num]=coords
        else:
            continue
```

### Problem

When the program is run, the plots don't contain any data as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01ydB.png). I would like to know what is going wrong here, and a solution to help achieve the goal.

Comment: `display.display(fig)` shows the png image of the plot. You cannot click or otherwise interact with png images.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the change and now observe that the plot doesn't contain any data. Please see my edited code and the attached picture.

Comment: So now you are using the nbagg backend (`%matplotlib notebook`)? Then `inline` needs to be removed. However, you will also need to rethink the complete structure, because you will need a single figure, whose content is changed in the loop. As to why there is no content: you never call `plt.show()` or otherwise `draw` the figure.

Comment: I have removed inline and included plt.show(). Still, the result is similar, there is no content on the plot.

Comment: I cannot run your code, right?! So all I can do is give you some hints. As said above, "you will need a single figure, whose content is changed in the loop.".

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving plt.show() after mpl_connect and closing the figure after you have reached the desired number of components did the trick. I have added some debug statements to help with following the flow of the code.

```
       plt.close("all")
       colour = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black', 'magenta']
       for num in range(len(df_car)):

           print '\n--------------\n'
           print 'Current Entry: '+str(num)
           print '\n--------------\n'
           print df_car.loc[num]
           print '\n\n'

           coords = defaultdict(list)

           for car, models in car.items():
               fig = plt.figure()
               ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
               i = 0

               for model in models.items():
                   ax.plot(spec[car+model[0]+'_Vel'][(spec[car+model[0]+'_Vel'] <= df_car['VEL_MAX'][num]) & (spec[car+model[0]+'_Vel'] >= df_car['VEL_MIN'][num])],
                           spec['FLUX'][(spec[car+model[0]+'_Vel'] <= df_car['VEL_MAX'][num]) & (spec[car+model[0]+'_Vel'] >= df_car['VEL_MIN'][num])], color=colour[i])
                   ax.set_ylim(-0.15, 1.25)
                   ax.set_title(car+'_'+str(num), fontsize=20,
                                family='serif', color='black')
                   i = i+1

               print '\n--------------\n'
               print 'car: ' + car
               print '\n--------------\n'

               ques = raw_input('Do you want to store components for above car? ')

               if ques == 'y' or ques == 'Y':
                   ques1 = input('Enter the number of components: ')

                   def onclick(event):
                       global ix, iy
                       ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
                       print ('x = %d, y = %d' % (ix, iy))
                       coords[car].append((ix, iy))
                       if len(coords[car]) == ques1:
                           fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
                           plt.close(fig)
                       return coords

                   cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
                   plt.draw()
                   plt.show()
               else:
                   continue

           df_car['COMPONENTS'][num] = coords
           print '\n--------------\n'
           print 'Updated Entry:::'
           print '\n--------------\n'
           print df_car.loc[num]
           print '\n'
           plt.close('all')
```